# Colors missing when calling grep through script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep

Here is a simple wrapper for grep for searching through a Git repository. For some reason, the colors are gone when grep is called though a bash script. How do I fix it?

[image]

I was using this command

```
grep $1 . -R --exclude-dir=.git --line-number
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run `grep` in a terminal it shows colours because of this default alias in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

`~/.bashrc` is only sourced by interactive shells. When you run a script, it runs in a non-interactive shell, so the alias is not available.

To preserve the colouring, add the `--color=auto` flag to the `grep` command inside the script:

```
grep $1 . -R --exclude-dir=.git --line-number --color=auto
```

Comment: Also note that with `--color=auto`, colors will be lost if you redirect the output (a good thing).

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Except when you pipe it to something like `less`, in which case you have to specify `--color=always` *and* use `less -R` to display the coloured output inside `less`.